# @DateTimeFormat in Spring gives wrong date

Tags: java, spring, date, datetime

I have a method that has a parameter annotated with @DateTimeFormat.

```
public static void exampleMethod(@ApiParam(value = "date", required = true)
                                 @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") Date date) {...}
```

When it gets "2021-05-13", **date** variable contains "2021-05-12" for some reason. What other similar annotations or date data types I can use to avoid this bug?

Thank in advance.

Comment: Seems like a timezone issue. DateTimeFormat goes with UTC time. So you must provide something like `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX`. Read more [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

A `java.util.Date` object simply represents an instant on the timeline — a wrapper around the number of milliseconds since the UNIX epoch (January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT). Since it does not hold any timezone information, it is the JVM's timezone that gets applied by default while parsing/formatting using `SimeplDateFormat`, which could be the root cause of the problem in your case.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:** Change the type of `date` field to [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) as follows:

```
public static void exampleMethod(
        @ApiParam(value = "date", required = true)
        @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) LocalDate date) {...}
```

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

#### In case you want to use `java.util.Date`:

As per the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/annotation/DateTimeFormat.html#pattern--):

> Whenever the [`iso()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/annotation/DateTimeFormat.html#iso--) attribute is used when formatting Date values, UTC
> will be used as the time zone.

So, all you need to do is to use `iso()` attribute i.e.

```
public static void exampleMethod(
        @ApiParam(value = "date", required = true)
        @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) Date date) {...}
```

---

<sup>* If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table). Note that Android 8.0 Oreo already provides [support for `java.time`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/package-summary).</sup>

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I did what you said but got the error: "message": "Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.Instant'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@io.swagger.annotations.ApiParam org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam java.time.Instant] for value '2021-10-12'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse attempt failed for value [2021-10-12]",

Comment: @EvgeniaRubanova - I have updated the solution. Hopefully, it will resolve the issue. Feel free to comment in case of any further issues/doubts.

Comment: Thank you again, your solution works for the case! But I just figured out that I need to use "Date" type here because of the external libraries. So, don't you know is there any way to add time (HH:mm:ss.SSSX) so that the date is determined correctly. My request contains nothing but year, month and day (yyyy-MM-dd).

Comment: @EvgeniaRubanova - Great! I have added one more update using which you should be able to work with `java.util.Date`.

Comment: Hello, Arvind! Unfortunately, my problem is here again:( I use @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) but the date I get is the previous one. I wonder if you could give me any advice or another solution... Thank you in advance! Moreover, my request contains the date without time (2021-10-12) but the Date date I get after @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) is Mon Oct 11 23:00:00 MSK 2021. And the time is always 23:00:00.

Comment: I've created a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69665145/datetimeformat-in-spring-returns-the-previous-day