# @DateTimeFormat in Spring returns the previous day

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, date, datetime

I have a method that has a parameter annotated with @DateTimeFormat.

```
public static void exampleMethod(@ApiParam(value = "date", required = true)
                                 @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) Date date) {...}
```

When it gets "2021-10-12", ***date*** variable contains "Mon Oct 11 23:00:00 MSK 2021" for some reason. My request doesn't have any time but what I get is the previous date and always 23:00:00.

I really need to use `Date` data type here, so what can be done to fix this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I wouldn't cross packages.  Use the older SimpleDateFormat for formatting java.util.Date instead of the newer java.time.DateTimeFormat.

Comment: It is because of TimeZone. Your date variable has `MSK` time zone and looks like you'ev MSK time zone.

Comment: @duffymo But can it be done in the method's parameters like in my example?

Comment: `2021-10-12` (or `2021-10-12T00:00`) at UTC should be `Mon Oct 12 03:00:00 MSK 2021` because MSK is GMT+3. It's difficult to say anything beyond it without looking into the complete code. **Regarding time appearing in the string**: `java.util.Date` does not store the timezone or the format; it's simply a wrapper around the no. of milliseconds. Whatever value you see is simply the string formatted as `EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy` and using the default timezone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone ever comes across this problem, I managed to solve it using `java.sql.Date` (as it is a subclass of `java.util.Date`) and `@JsonFormat` annotation at the same time:

```
public static void exampleMethod(@ApiParam(value = "date", required = true)
                                 @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd") Date date) {...}
```